# Can stranded wire handle the same high voltage as solid core?

Tags: electrical, fence, wire

Two 10 AWG wires for an electric fence were cut by the lawn mowers. I read that electric fences have very low amperage. So a 30 A rating is well above the call of duty: 10-2 type UF-B cable with ground wire (stranded).

That is what's available locally. There is no voltage rating. Although, looking online, I find that similar stranded wires have 1000 VDC (TÜV). Does that mean they're rated only up to 1000 VDC? Or is this just something to do with [solar panels](http://www.amercable.com/doc/catalogs/renewable/solar.pdf)?

Edit - This wire is between the energizer and the fence, no man's land.

---

Aside, why does our electric fence have two wires? To [create an open circuit](https://www.agrisellex.co.uk/pages/what-is-electric-fencing), wouldn't you only need one?

Comment: Voltage and current are two different (though obviously related) things. Generally speaking, it is the **current** that determines the required wire size - e.g., 14 AWG for 15 A, 12 AWG for 20 A, etc. I suspect your electric fence uses relatively high voltage but very low current. As far as 1 wire vs. 2, I don't know exactly how an electric fence works, but keep in mind that you don't want to create an open circuit - that wouldn't be very useful. You want to create a complete circuit, which needs 2 wires. Otherwise what you have is likely both at times ineffective and at times deadly.

Comment: From the last link (https://www.agrisellex.co.uk/pages/what-is-electric-fencing), it shows how an open circuit is the whole idea. The circuit is complete when the animal touches the fence; the literal ground completes the circuit. And yes, it is very high voltage (4-7.5kV) and low current (where I can touch it).

Comment: stranded wire can handle more voltage than solid, due to better cooling and the skin effect. A wire's volts rating relates to the insulation, amps relates to the conductor.

Comment: It's special, but go down to Tractor Supply (or your country's equivalent).  Any farm supply in an agricultural area should have that stuff in stock.

Answer (score 1):

### No, you'll need the proper electric fence extension wire

The problem with a standard UF or equivalent cable is that the insulation is only rated for 600V, far less than the several thousand volts that an electric fence energizer puts out.  As a result, you'll need a specialized electric fence extension wire and matching splices that are rated for such high voltages to replace the damaged wire.  Using the wrong stuff *will* cause the wire insulation to break down and fail, leading to your fence grounding out.

Comment: How is [this 14 gauge solid-core](https://www.amazon.com/ElectroBraid-UGCC200-EB-Voltage-Insulated-Copper/dp/B00AU8G93E) different from [this 12 gauge solid-core](https://www.farmandfleet.com/products/004640-southwire-12-gauge-thhn-solid-conduit-wire.html)? Is it all based on the insulation's material properties?

Comment: @AdamUraynar -- exactly -- the electric fence wire has far more robust insulation on it to withstand the rigors of high voltage service

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the electric fence itself or the supply to the charger? Supply to the charger is plain old 18 ga line ( 120 V and low current). The fence itself is normally single strand aluminum bare wire ( very very high voltage and very low current); usually sold next to the chargers. The aluminum wire is marked 17 ga and it looks like it. I used 12 ga to the ground rod just for mechanical strength. The charger has two output connections , one to the fence and one to a ground rod; I used 10ft of 1/2 copper tubing and jetted it into the ground.

Comment: No, it is "for an electric fence." It's not the fence itself. A barn (with the energizer) is 175' away from the fence. It's between the energizer and the fence. Again, a lawnmower cut the two 10 gauge wires.